# Isn't an array/arrayname always a pointer to the first element in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What's going in below isn't an arrayname always a pointer to the first element in C?

```
int myArray[10] = {0};

printf("%d\n", &myArray); /* prints memadress for first element */
printf("%d\n", myArray); /* this prints a memadress too, shows that the name is a pointer */

printf("%d\n",sizeof(myArray)); /* this prints size of the whole array, not a pointer anymore? */
printf("%d\n",sizeof(&myArray)); /* this prints the size of the pointer */
```

Comment: In order to `printf` pointer values you should use `%p` format specifier. You are using `%d`, which is completely meaningless thing to do.

Comment: The C FAQ seems to have gone down, but you Google "c faq arrays" and access the cached edition.

Comment: @AndreyT what do you mean meaningless, you get it in decimal with %d and hexadecimal with %p, right, but you're point may be memory is in hexa by def?

Comment: A pointer is a different datatype from an integer (or long) and may have internal structure that's not suitable for displaying with an integer format. Example: In Turbo C on 386, pointers were segment:offset (i.e. 2 integers) and had special formatting with %p; outputting with %d would have either failed or hidden some information.

Comment: And on x86_64 %p wants an 8 byte data type, while %d is only 4 bytes.

Comment: @Chris_45: `%d` specifier requires a parameter value of type `int` and only of type `int`. If parameter value has any other type, the behavior is undefined. If you for some reason want to print a pointer with `%d`, you have to explicitly cast the pointer argument to `int` type. Nevertheless, it still doesn't make much sense, since `int` is not an appropriate type to cast a pointer to. At least use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` (with the corresponding format specifier), but not an `int`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Array name is array name. Array name is an identifier that identifies the entire array object. It is not a pointer to anything.

When array name is used in an expression the array type gets automatically implicitly converted to pointer-to-element type in *almost* all contexts (this is often referred to as "array type decay"). The resultant pointer is a completely independent temporary rvalue. It has nothing to do with the array itself. It has nothing to do with the array name.

The two exceptions when the implicit conversion does not take place is: operator `sizeof` and unary operator `&` (address-of). This is exactly what you tested in your code.

Comment: But it isn't an identifier like with ints, doubles and so on for example you can't do like this: int myArray1[] = {0}; int myArray2[] = {0}; myArray2 = myArray1; - this would be like saying 1 = 3  ?

Comment: It is an identifier, it just can't be assigned to. Another identifier which can't be assigned to is this one: `const int a = 0;`, although not really for the same reason.

Comment: @Chris_45: It is identifier "like with ints", except that the assignment operator context is not excluded from the set of contexts where "array type decay" takes place. The result of that is that arrays are non-modifiable lvalues (as Steve said).

Answer (score 5):

Be wary of the types.

- The type of `myArray` is `int[10]`.
- The type of `&myArray` is `int (*)[10]` (pointer to `int[10]`).
- When evaluated, the type of `myArray` is `int *`. I.e. the type of the **value** of `myArray` is `int *`.
- sizeof does not evaluate its argument. Hence `sizeof(myArray) == sizeof(int[10]) != sizeof(int *)`.

Corollary:

- `myArray` and `&myArray` are incompatible pointer types, and are not interchangeable.

You cannot correctly assign `&myArray` to a variable of type `int *foo`.

Answer (score 4):

An array is not a pointer.  However, if an array name is used in an expression where it is not the subject of either the `&` operator or the `sizeof` operator, it will evaluate to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: But how come this is true:
int *point;
point == myArray;
point == &myArray[0];

Comment: Because in both those cases, `myArray` is *not* the subject of either `&` or `sizeof`, so it evaluates to a pointer to its first element - that is, `&myArray[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

No, an array *is* that first element (and the rest). It doesn't get converted into a pointer until you pass it as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 1):

`arrayname` will point to all the elements of the array. That is the reason you can do
`(arrayname + 5)` to point to the 5th element in the array.

Comment: what I mean here is that arrayname points to entire object not any single element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

An arrayname is not a pointer, but it can be treated as a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

do arrayname++ and u will come to know that arrayname at a time represents the whole array and not only the starting element....by default it keeps the starting address of the first element