# Should I cast arrays to pointers when passing them to variadic functions like printf?

Tags: c++, c, printf

Can I pass an array to printf directly:

```
char text[1024] = "text";
printf("%s", text);
```

Or should I explicitly cast it to a char pointer:

```
char text[1024] = "text";
printf("%s", (char*) text);
```

I'm asking because I thought maybe it copies the array elements directly into the va_list instead of putting just a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Just don't forget the null terminator.

Comment: @sje397: "text" is  {'t','e','x','t',0}

Comment: Yes stefan, but if you are manipulating arrays (and asking this question) it is something to remember.

Comment: @sje397 Why do you need to remember that there is a zero terminator? The array always automatically gets it, it's part of the text the array is initialised with. Moreover, the way this array is created, all the chars after the first four get initialised to zero as well.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's directly relevant. I just suppose that it's likely someone who is storing text in arrays will be doing things like copying text from one array to another. Also, if such a person is a relative beginner, as this question suggests to me, then they may want to be aware of things like the fact that `strlen` will return a number less than the number of bytes you usually want to copy. Just trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an array directly. Exactly, name of array represents address of the array which makes no difference with `char *`.

Answer (score 4):

`(char*)text` and `text` hardly make any difference in this example! Base address of an array decays into a pointer when passed as a function argument.

In fact, even if `text` was not a `char` array, still it would hardly make any difference to `printf` because it is a variable argument function

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

and all it cares is about the first argument. Logic might go wrong but `printf` doesn't care!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes, <strike>arrays in C _are_a pointer to their first element.</strike>  (Edit: Longer answer, well, actually, arrays in C are identifiers or labels which are just names, but when used as part of an expression that doesn't preface them with & or sizeof they get converted into or otherwise evaluated as pointers).

Even longer answer: You see, functions can't really receive an array as an argument, but the compiler has to send them something, so it sends them a pointer. Thus the first sentence should probably start with "As far as functions like `printf()` are concerned..."

Some functions purport to take an array, but that's just an illusion. These two functions are the same.

```
func(char *a);
func(char a[]);
```

The C FAQ entry below goes into more detail about the subtle differences between arrays and pointers:

```
char a[] = "this";
char *b = "that";
```

a[0] generates completely different code than b[0] yet they are roughly equivalent in that the subscripting operator [] gives us the expected result.

Interestingly, the format specifier "%s\n" is also passed to `printf()` as a pointer.

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

[Isn't an array/arrayname always a pointer to the first element in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845594/isnt-an-array-arrayname-always-a-pointer-to-the-first-element-in-c)

Comment: The first sentence is correct. The second is not. Arrays in C are arrays. Pointers in C are pointers. Arrays are not pointers (otherwise, there would be no automatic conversion, as you yourself mentioned in the first sentence)

Comment: Actually, the first sentence is _not_ correct. Arrays are _not_ pointers. They decay to pointers in many circumstances (not all) but just try incrementing an array and a pointer - the latter works, the former does not: `char x[10]; char *y = x; x++; y++;` will not work for `x++`.

Comment: Closer to the "machine", arrays are nothing but data located somewhere. The "obvious" way to access array of elements in memory (these data) is through a pointer. But far from the machine PoV, given `T a[N]`, `a` must be an immutable *reference* (pointer) to the first element; maybe it can be said simply that it can't be a *lvalue* exactly as `&(a[0])`, and this justifies the failure of `a++`. So I would say, `a` is just syntactic sugar for `&(a[0])` and being so it is correct to say `a` is just a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Edited to use language that is less ambiguous while trying not to plagiarize. Found the reference I was looking for in the c faq.

Answer (score 1):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be replaced by an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the address of the first element of the array.

When you write

```
printf("%s", text);
```

the expression `text` is replaced by a new expression of type `char *` whose value is `&text[0]`, and this pointer value is what gets passed to `printf`.  This means you don't have to cast the argument.  It also means that you cannot pass an array expression as a function parameter and have the called function receive it as an array *type*.  The conversion happens before the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

names of pointers and arrays are exchangeable. (Besides the memory allocation)

When you have

```
char *a = "abcdef";
char b[5];
```

You could write

```
char z = a[2]; // 'c'
char x = *b;
char y = *(b+2);
```

But you can't do

```
b ++;
```

You may consider `array b` as `char * const b` as a unmodifyable pointer